# ReactNative Android all requests fail while iOS works

Tags: javascript, android, connection, react-native

### Suddenly while debugging Android all network requests fail, but within iOS, it works.

`curl --data "email=test@gmail.com" https://unblnd.com/api/login` works correctly and provides the expected result. Using http the request returns moved permanently, but as the local connection does not work either this should not be the problem?

It fails on android physical devices and android emulators within both localhost and remote API URLs.

*`$ react-native info`*

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
  ...
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

*Config file*

```
if (__DEV__) {
  config = {
    clientId: '***',
    url: 'http://192.168.0.***:8000/api',
  };
} else {
  config = {
    clientId: '***',
    url: 'http://unblnd.com/api',
  };
}
```

*We made this fetchApi function that takes care of get and post methods*

```
import apiConfig from './config';
import * as authSelectors from 'app/services/auth/selectors';

export const fetchApi = async (endPoint, method = 'get', body = {}) => {
  console.log(`start fetchApi ${method} ${endPoint}`);
  const accessToken = authSelectors.get().tokens.access.value;
  const accessType = authSelectors.get().tokens.access.type;
  let headers = {
    ...(accessToken
      ? {
          Authorization: `${accessType} ${accessToken}`,
          Accept: 'application/json',
        }
      : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
  };
  let response;
  if (method == 'get' || Object.keys(body) == 0) {
    response = await fetch(`${apiConfig.url}${endPoint}`, {
      method: method,
      headers: headers,
    });
  } else {
    var formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(body).forEach(type => {
      if (typeof body[type] === 'object') {
        body[type] = JSON.stringify(body[type]);
      }
      formData.append(type, body[type]);
    });
    console.log('sending data: ' + JSON.stringify(formData));
    response = await fetch(`${apiConfig.url}${endPoint}`, {
      method: method,
      headers: headers,
      body: formData,
    });
  }
  console.log('fetch response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
  let responseJsonData = await response.json();
  console.log('fetch response json: ' + JSON.stringify(responseJsonData));
  return responseJsonData;
};
```

What has been tried?

- `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` has been added to AndroidManifest.xml;
- File res/xml/network_security_config.xml has been added;
- Using tools:...

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.unblnd">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      tools:targetApi="23">
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

There are similar topics to this questions, but it did not seem to help to add the hacks to the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution please?

Comment: We do not have a clear sight of a clean solution, but it helped to delete `FormData` and just use `JSON.stringify(body)`. It also helped to always use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` within the headers. This helped within production, but not in localhost. Do any of these tips help you out?